# Diagonal invariants of $SO(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

Consider a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (I am mostly interested in the case $\mathfrak g=so(n)$), its universal enveloping algebra $U$ and its center $C$. There is an adjoint action of $\mathfrak g$ on $U_{12}=U\otimes U$,
$$
[g,u_1\otimes u_2]=[g,u_1]\otimes u_2+u_1\otimes [g,u_2].
$$
Let $C_{12}$ be the subalgebra of $U_{12}$ invariant under this action, $$C_{12}=\{u\in U_{12}:\forall g\in \mathfrak{g},\,[g,u]=0\}.$$

How can I describe $C_{12}$? Is it generated by $C_1=C\otimes 1$, $C_2=1\otimes C$ and $C_3$ the diagonal embedding of $C$ into $U_{12}$ (induced by the embedding $g\mapsto g\otimes 1+1\otimes g$)? What about larger tensor products?